# telegram bot using rasa with the help of ngrok is not working

Tags: telegram, webhooks, telegram-bot, ngrok, rasa

I'm developing a Telegram bot using rasa and want to use ngrok to receive messages from the webhook.

Setting a webhook works. When I set my publicly reachable domain as URL,and try to run bot on telegram nothing comes out. There is no reply from bot.

'''

```
ngrok by @inconshreveable                                                                                                         

Session Status                online
Session Expires               7 hours, 43 minutes
Version                       2.3.35
Region                        United States (us)
Web Interface                 http://127.0.0.1:4040
Forwarding                    http://ef87f17b7c55.ngrok.io -> http://mybot.myserver.com:80
Forwarding                    https://ef87f17b7c55.ngrok.io -> http://mybot.myserver.com:80

Connections                   ttl     opn     rt1     rt5     p50     p90
                              20      0       0.02    0.02    1.01    3.01
```

'''

when I am trying to run on telegram, nothing comes out and bad gateway error is coming.

ngrok's CLI output:

'''

```
POST    /webhooks/telegram/webhook 502 Bad Gateway
POST    /webhooks/telegram/webhook 502 Bad Gateway
POST    /webhooks/telegram/webhook 502 Bad Gateway
POST    /webhooks/telegram/webhook 502 Bad Gateway
POST    /webhooks/telegram/webhook 502 Bad Gateway
POST    /webhooks/telegram/webhook 502 Bad Gateway
OPTIONS /webhooks/rest/webhook     502 Bad Gateway
POST    /webhooks/telegram/webhook 502 Bad Gateway
POST    /webhooks/telegram/webhook 502 Bad Gateway
POST    /webhooks/telegram/webhook 502 Bad Gateway
```

'''

Answer (score 0):

what is the output on the console? Try running your bot with `rasa run --debug` and you should get some helpful output that shows what's going wrong. There could be an issue with your credentials

Comment: when I run "rasa run --debug" command, it is working fine on cosole ( Rasa server is up and running.)  . Main problem is that I am not able to receive reply from telegram named (rasa) in my case.   Every time I am getting "502 Bad Gateway" error in ngrok console.

Comment: but in your shell (where you ran `rasa run --debug`) , you don't see any errors?